# Loading Custom Script Extensions from Github for an Azure VM

Tags: azure

I am setting up an Azure Windows VM, and looking to use Custom Script Extensions for some On Boot scripting.

Many write ups about Custom Script Extensions talk about being able to load the script from Blob and/or Github. However when I go to add a CSE via the Portal, this is what I see :

[image]

So I can give the script file from my local machine and that's it it seems?

Comment: i believe this script gets uploaded to a blob storage and is fetched and run whenever the VM is provisioned. Normally in powershell scripts we would provide the blob url where the startup scripts are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Azure portal, you use the extension as you see, and the script file will be uploaded from your local machine as it seems. After you upload the script file you can see that it is stored in the Azure storage blob and the URL will be like this: https://iaasv2tempstoreeastus.blob.core.windows.net/vmextensionstemporary-10030000aa9b4851-20180717014522123/Untitled1.ps1.

When you want to use a custom script file from Blob and/or Github, you would need to use the PowerShell cmdlet [`Set-AzureRmVMExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmextension?view=azurermps-6.4.0), and will be like this:

```
$SettingsString = '{"fileUris":[],"commandToExecute":""}';
$ProtectedSettingsString = '{"storageAccountName":"' + $stoname + '","storageAccountKey":"' + $stokey + '"}';
Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -Location "West US" -VMName "VirtualMachine22" -Name "CustomScriptExtension" -Publisher "Contoso.Compute" -Type "CustomScriptExtension" -TypeHandlerVersion "1.1" -SettingString $SettingsString -ProtectedSettingString $ProtectedSettingsString ;
```

You can set the `fileUrls` with your script file link from Blob and/or Github so that you can use it as the custom script.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command on Azure CLI:

```
az vm extension set --resource-group <Your azure resource group name> --vm-name <your vm name> --name customScript --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions --settings <customscript.json>
```

Here in this example, the **<customscript.json>** file contains:

```
{
"fileUris":["<Generate raw github link to your .sh file and put that link.>"],
"commandToExecute":"./<Your same .sh file in github>"
}
```